# Webpack: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, webpack, bundle

My application runs fine in development, but whenever I deploy it to production I am provided with the error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <". Whenever I inspect the source of the error, it is due to the webpack bundle loading index.html instead of the anticipated javascript /assets/js/index.js.

I deduce that this is Webpack ignoring every request outside of index.html, but nowhere in any configurations do I have it pointing at it as default. I'd like to know how to remedy this issue and have it render what's configured as the entry point.

Traceback:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">  
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--<title></title>-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="container"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/assets/bundles/main-210eb139915d8d6abedf.js" ></script>
  </body>
```

webpack.config.js

```
//require our dependencies
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')

module.exports = {
    //the base directory (absolute path) for resolving the entry option
    context: __dirname,
    //the entry point we created earlier. Note that './' means 
    //your current directory. You don't have to specify the extension  now,
    //because you will specify extensions later in the `resolve` section
  entry: [
      './assets/js/index'
  ],    
  output: {
      path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/'), 
      filename: "[name]-[hash].js"
  },

    plugins: [
        //tells webpack where to store data about your bundles.
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(), // don't reload if there is an error
        new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}), 
        //makes jQuery available in every module
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ 
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery' 
        })
    ],

  module: {
    loaders: [
      // we pass the output from babel loader to react-hot loader
      { 
        test: [/\.js$/, /\.es6$/, /\.jsx?$/],
        exclude: /node_modules/, 
        loaders: ['babel'], 
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
    ]
  },

    resolve: {
        //tells webpack where to look for modules
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
        //extensions that should be used to resolve modules
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'] 
    }   
}
```

Comment: Kindly add the complete traceback.

Comment: I updated it to include the index.html. There really isn't a traceback, as webpack just outputs `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Answer (score 2):

Try to directly access the `JS` or `CSS` file directly on browser, if you are seeing is a 404 error, then you are not handling static files correctly.
you can use [dj-static](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-static) or configure main HTTP server ( Apache or Nginx) handle `static` file requests.

What happening here is that webpack is trying to load the js files to JS environment, but the url request results in an html file ( probably a 404 error) causing JS syntax error ( xml/html).

Comment: The JS and CSS files are directly accessible through the browser. As far as static files are concerned, the whitenoise.py plugin is taking care of managing them.

Comment: check the network tab that to which url the requests is going and what is the response

Comment: All of the paths are as expected. 200 on every one. My suspicion is that webpack cannot find the file I specified as an entry point and defaults to index.html instead.